# Is there any standard delete functor?

Tags: c++, functor, delete-operator

I am looking for a functor that deletes its argument:

```
template<class T>
struct delete_functor
{
    void operator()(T* p)
    {
        delete p;
    }
};
```

Is there something like this in `std`, `tr1` or `boost`?

Comment: If you were writing this yourself, btw, then with `struct delete_functor { template <typename T> void operator()(T* p) { delete p; } };`, you don't have to specify T when you create one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++0x will add `std::default_delete` to the standard library to support `std::unique_ptr`.

It has effectively the same functionality as your `delete_functor`, but is also specialized to call `delete[]` for array type objects.

Comment: What does `std::default_delete<void>()` do?

Comment: @user1095108:  If the `operator()` is instantiated, the program would be ill-formed.  The type with which `default_delete` is instantiated may be incomplete at the time the class template is instantiated, but it must be complete when the `operator()` is instantiated.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis So one must instantiate `std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)> p{ 0, operator delete };` to delete `void*` correctly?

Comment: @user1095108:  The operand of `delete` may not be a `void*`.  If you attempt to `delete` a `void*`, the program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 2):

Boost.Lambda has [delete_ptr and delete_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#table:constructor_destructor_fos)

Comment: `#include <boost/lambda/construct.hpp>`

Answer (score 0):

We are not allowed to use boost in my company, and we're not using C++11 either, so I use this:

```
namespace
{
  // - for use to deletion:
  // std::vector<int*> foobar;
  // std::for_each(foobar.begin(), fooabr.end(), del_fun<T>());
  template<class _Type>
  struct del_fun_t:
    public unary_function<_Type*, void>
  {
    void operator()(_Type* __ptr) {
      delete __ptr;
    }
  };

  template<class _Type>
  del_fun_t<_Type> del_fun()
  {
    return del_fun_t<_Type>();
  };
};
```

I think that's what you're looking for.

You can also recreate it as dtor_fun_t and replace "delete _*ptr;" by "*_ptr->~_Type();" to only call the dtor. This would be the case where you used a memory manager and placement new for example.